# How to prompt for user input and place that value in a terminal command using applescript?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to create a script that asks the user what .mp3 they want to split using Terminal through AppleScript / Script Editor. Here's what I have so far.

I am trying to get input to display in this line:

```
do script "spleeter separate -i (text returned of input).mp3 -p spleeter:2stems -o output"
```

in terminal, it just says that there are no matches found for (text returned of input).

Here's my code:

```
set input to display dialog "What would you like to convert?" default answer "" with icon note buttons {"Continue", "Cancel"} default button "Continue"

tell application "Terminal"
    do script "cd Desktop/spleetr"
    do script "spleeter separate -i (text returned of input).mp3 -p spleeter:2stems -o output"
    
end tell
```

Comment: Do you need to run this in a Terminal window (view output, etc)?  Note that you are running two separate Terminal scripts.

Comment: @red_menace yeah. the program i’m using is called spleeter and it’s a command line program

Comment: There are a few ways to run command line programs,  my question was if you needed to run in a terminal to get some kind of feedback vs just running the utility (`do shell script`, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are placing a command inside a string, so it is not getting evaluated.  The solution for that is to concatenate the results of the command and the string parts in the desired order.

When using the Terminal, unless specified otherwise, each `do script` command is run in its own window/tab.  If you don't neccessarily need a Terminal window, the `do shell script` command can be used instead (note that it uses a default shell, so you should use full paths), but to use multiple commands with either one you need to combine the various shell commands into a single statement, otherwise they will be run in separate shells.

I don't have that utility to test, but in the following script I am getting the text in the dialog statement, and quoting the result for the shell script in case it contains spaces, etc:

```
set input to text returned of (display dialog "What would you like to convert?" default answer "" with icon note buttons {"Continue", "Cancel"} default button "Continue")

-- to run in a new Terminal window: --

tell application "Terminal"
   do script "cd Desktop/spleetr; spleeter separate -i " & quoted form of (input & ".mp3") & " -p spleeter:2stems -o output"
end tell

-- or if Terminal is not needed: --

do shell script "cd Desktop/spleetr; spleeter separate -i " & quoted form of (input & ".mp3") & " -p spleeter:2stems -o output"
```